# 1 Hz Clock Signal With CD4060 vs CD4521

Tags: digital-logic, oscillator, clock, crystal

I am building DIY digital clocks as a school side project. I need to generate a 1 Hz clock signal. I currently have some 32.768kHz crystals but I need to choose an IC.

I don’t want to build the oscillator circuit. Would rather use a IC.

I’ve seen suggestions on here to use the CD4060 with a flip flop to divide the clock down to 1 Hz.

Another suggestion I’ve seen is to use a CD4521 because supposedly it can directly take a 32.768kHz crystal to produce a 1 Hz signal. This seems like the better option but can anyone confirm this?

Comment: The lowest stage you can access on the CD4521 is Q18. When you trigger it with a 32768Hz crystal, you get a 0.25Hz signal. Not 1Hz. Please see the datasheets for reference. They have reasonable application circuits too usually.

Comment: So with the CD4521 is it the crystal that determines the frequency or is there a way to control the frequency division? I’ve been reading data-sheets daily but since i’m an amateur it’s easier to hear it from someone on here in plain language.

Answer (score 3):

Neither the 4060 nor the 4521 will get you to a 1Hz output from a 32768 Hz crystal by itself.

You need a division of 2^15. The least a 4521 will divide by is 2^17. The most a 4060 will divide by is 2^14, which needs another /2 from some suitable source. You could use an HC74, or CD4013, or one stage of an HC393 or 390, there are a lot of different ICs that will give you an extra /2 function.

Neither the 4060 nor the 4521 are programmable. They both divide by different numbers, and put all those outputs on the output pins simultaneously. You select which frequency you want by choosing the pin to take the output from. You could do this with a multiplexer if you wanted electronic control of the output frequency.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I know that the 4060 will need a flip flop and is not programmable. I’m purposely using these chips instead of microcontrollers. I’m asking if the 4521 would be a better choice than the 4060 but based on your info it sounds like a bad choice. Someone in another post claimed that the 4521 can divide by 15 but that seems to be false info.

Comment: "I’m asking if the 4521 would be a better choice"  *we can't tell you*, because your situation determines your best choice.

Comment: I just need a 1 Hz clock signal for a digital clock. That’s all there is to it basically. I’m using counter IC’s

Comment: You need an oscillator circuit of some kind nevertheless.

Comment: @Janka   both 4060 and 4521 include the oscillator

Answer (score 0):

You can use two CD4060s to get 1Hz: use 32768Hz crystal (CD4060 #1 input pin 11- Clock, Output pin 15 -divide by 1024 >>> CD4060 #2 Input Pin 11-Clock, Output pin 5 -divide by 32 = 1Hz)

Comment: Note that this thread died out over four years ago.